# Recover bricked unrooted Moto G5 (bootloop)

Tags: fastboot, boot-loop, unbricking, motorola-moto-g5

My Moto G5 got stuck right after booting into Android, screen frozen at my Andorid home screen and was not responding. It was charging but battery was dead, like 1%. Don't know if that caused the issue. I had to remove the battery to turn it off.

After that it never booted again: does start up animations, then asks the PIN, then remains stuck on Motorola logo.I suspect it is bricked?
I **really** want to  recover data but sadly it is not rooted, with no custom recovery. Just plain stock Android.

I am able to enter fastboot and adb (with Stock recovery). Here's the getvar output

```
(bootloader) version: 0.5
(bootloader) version-bootloader: moto-msm8937-B8.31
(bootloader) product: cedric
(bootloader) board: cedric
(bootloader) secure: yes
(bootloader) hwrev: P5
(bootloader) radio: 7
(bootloader) storage-type: emmc
(bootloader) emmc: 16GB SAMSUNG QE13MB RV=08 PV=0D FV=000000000000000D
(bootloader) ram: 2GB SAMSUNG LP3 DIE=8Gb M5=01 M6=05 M7=00 M8=1F
(bootloader) cpu: MSM8937
(bootloader) serialno: ZY32256S53
(bootloader) cid: 0x0032
(bootloader) channelid: 0x5b
(bootloader) uid: 153EB23800000000000000000000
(bootloader) securestate: oem_locked
(bootloader) iswarrantyvoid: no
(bootloader) max-download-size: 535822336
(bootloader) reason: Volume down key pressed
(bootloader) imei: xxxxx
(bootloader) meid:
(bootloader) date: 06-13-2017
(bootloader) sku: XT1675
(bootloader) carrier_sku:
(bootloader) battid:
(bootloader) iccid:
(bootloader) cust_md5:
(bootloader) max-sparse-size: 268435456
(bootloader) current-time: "Thu Jan  1  0: 6:47 UTC 1970"
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[0]: motorola/cedric_timit/cedric:8.1.0
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[1]: /OPP28.85-13/789a:user/release-key
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[2]: s
(bootloader) poweroffalarm: 0
(bootloader) ro.build.version.full[0]: Blur_Version.28.41.12.cedric_timi
(bootloader) ro.build.version.full[1]: t.timit.en.US
(bootloader) ro.build.version.qcom: LA.UM.6.6.r1-08600-89xx.0
(bootloader) version-baseband: M8937_22.29.02.69R CEDRIC_EMEA_CUST
(bootloader) kernel.version[0]: Linux version 3.18.71-perf-ga19fa3e (hud
(bootloader) kernel.version[1]: soncm@ilclbld34) (gcc version 4.8 (GCC)
(bootloader) kernel.version[2]: ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 17 09:23:26 CDT
(bootloader) kernel.version[3]:  2018
(bootloader) sbl1.git: git=MBM-NG-VB8.31-0-g77d3670
(bootloader) rpm.git: git=MBM-NG-VB8.31-0-gbd76357-dirty
(bootloader) tz.git: git=MBM-NG-VB8.31-1-g26cc248
(bootloader) devcfg.git: git=MBM-NG-VB8.31-1-g26cc248
(bootloader) keymaster.git: git=MBM-NG-VB8.31-1-g26cc248
(bootloader) cmnlib.git: git=MBM-NG-VB8.31-1-g26cc248
(bootloader) cmnlib64.git: git=MBM-NG-VB8.31-1-g26cc248
(bootloader) prov.git: git=MBM-NG-VB8.31-1-g26cc248
(bootloader) aboot.git: git=MBM-NG-VB8.31-0-g0b9dae9
(bootloader) frp-state: protected (77)
(bootloader) ro.carrier: timit
(bootloader) current-slot:
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: _a
(bootloader) slot-count: 1
(bootloader) slot-successful:_a: INVALID
(bootloader) slot-successful:_b: INVALID
(bootloader) slot-bootable:_a: INVALID
(bootloader) slot-bootable:_b: INVALID
(bootloader) slot-retry-count:_a: unknown
(bootloader) slot-retry-count:_b: unknown
all: listed above
Finished. Total time: 0.062s
```

Is there any way to find out what is causing Android not to boot? which file/partition got corrupted, if any?
I understand that there are several "images" in a Stock ROM, such as gpt.img, boot.img, oem.img... I am not sure about flashing these because I don't want to lose my data forever

Answer (score 1):

If you still have access to Fastboot, you can use Motorola's Rescue and Smart Assistant.

Or if you wanna do it manually, download Motorola's USB drivers and get your firmware from
https://mirrors-obs-2.lolinet.com/firmware/motorola/2017/cedric/official/TIMIT/,
then flash it manually through Fastboot/Bootloader. Make sure you match the fingerprint of the device. There are files in the zip called `flashfile` and `servicefile` in XML format. I converted the `servicefile` to flash instructions. The `flashfile` includes erasing userdata and cache which I didn't include below.

```
fastboot getvar max-sparse-size
fastboot oem fb_mode_set
fastboot flash partition gpt.bin
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader.img
fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin
fastboot flash fsg fsg.img
fastboot erase modemst1
fastboot erase modemst2
fastboot flash dsp adspso.bin
fastboot flash logo logo.bin
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.3
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.4
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.5
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.6
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.7
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.8
fastboot flash oem oem.img
fastboot erase DDR
fastboot oem fb_mode_clear
```

Comment: i did it, all commands run with success but still nothing, phone boots, asks PIN then gets stuck on Motorola Logo forever :(